# What is periodogram?

Tags: r, spectral-analysis

I have read about spectral density and periodogram from couple of books,still just one example from R code showed that I do not understand the theory.I have this data set

```
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385348912800e+02
-9.385236201600e+02
-9.385236201600e+02
-9.385123490400e+02
-9.385123490400e+02
-9.385236201600e+02
-9.385198631200e+02
-9.385236201600e+02
-9.385198631200e+02
-9.385085920000e+02
-9.385085920000e+02
-9.385085920000e+02
-9.385198631200e+02
-9.385311342400e+02
-9.385386483200e+02
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385649476000e+02
-9.385762187200e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.385912468800e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.385987609600e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.385987609600e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.385874898400e+02
-9.385762187200e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385762187200e+02
-9.385762187200e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386100320800e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.385950039200e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.385687046400e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385687046400e+02
-9.385611905600e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385611905600e+02
-9.385912468800e+02
-9.385874898400e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385574335200e+02
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385386483200e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385273772000e+02
-9.385236201600e+02
-9.385198631200e+02
-9.385198631200e+02
-9.385273772000e+02
-9.385348912800e+02
-9.385386483200e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385611905600e+02
-9.385687046400e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385649476000e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385386483200e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385386483200e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385461624000e+02
-9.385611905600e+02
-9.385762187200e+02
-9.385687046400e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385536764800e+02
-9.385424053600e+02
-9.385499194400e+02
-9.385574335200e+02
-9.385611905600e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385837328000e+02
-9.385837328000e+02
-9.385874898400e+02
-9.385950039200e+02
-9.385950039200e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.385950039200e+02
-9.385987609600e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.385950039200e+02
-9.385912468800e+02
-9.385837328000e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385724616800e+02
-9.385874898400e+02
-9.385799757600e+02
-9.385874898400e+02
-9.385987609600e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.385987609600e+02
-9.386025180000e+02
-9.386062750400e+02
-9.386100320800e+02
-9.386213032000e+02
-9.386213032000e+02
-9.386325743200e+02
```

R spectrum shows this [image]

If I change the last number to

```
-9.086325743200e+02
```

and leave the first 127 unchanged,the same R spectrum gives me

[image]

Why does the change of only one number influence power spectral density in this manner?Why is the frequency range from 0-0.5?Can someone elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More plainly put, your original data range from $-938.6326$ to $-938.5086$, a range of just $0.124$ (neglecting some finer detail).

Then you change the last value by adding $30$! (That's $30$, exclamation mark, not a factorial.)

The difference is about $250$ times the entire range of the rest of the data.

Now the spectrum is, in British terms, well and truly clobbered (sober translation: completely different), as the series is a combination of a trend imparted by the last value, a massive outlier, and minuscule variability in the rest of the data.

You seem to be thinking that your one change is small, but in spectrum terms the change is massive. It's arguable whether a spectrum makes any sense for such a series.

I could plot the data as a series for you, but you should have done that yourself to see what you did.

Comment: CoxThanks,can you just explain the frequency range?

Comment: You can work it out. What's the maximum frequency on which there can be information in a finite series?

Comment: Yes,I got it(1/2).